# First javascript script in head doesn't run, but second does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fairly new to javascript and jQuery and don't understand why only one of the two scripts in my head section is working.

I have the following code in the head of my page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function menu(){
        $('#nav_menu') .slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"});
    });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/jquery.bxslider.css">
<script src="./js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function slideshow(){
        $('#slider') .bxSlider({
            auto: true,
            autoControls: true,
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 10,
            slideWidth: 650, 
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in my body I have the following elements:

```
    <nav id="mobile_menu"></nav>
    <nav id="nav_menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="current" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./navigation/aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="./navigation/products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Promotions</a>
                <ul>
        <li><a href="./navigation/backtoschool.html">Back-To-School</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> What's New</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./navigation/latestnews.html">Latest News</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./navigation/team.html">Our Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="./navigation/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

and,

```
    <ul id="slider"> 
        <li><img src="./images/1.png" alt="Parrot Products"></li>
        <li><img src="images/2.png" alt="Office Machines"></li>
        <li><img src="images/3.png" alt="Labelling"></li>
        <li><img src="images/4.png" alt="Paper"></li>
        <li><img src="images/5.png" alt="Files &amp; filing"></li>
        <li><img src="images/6.png" alt="Office Accessories"></li>
        <li><img src="images/7.png" alt="Toners &amp; Cartridges"></li>
        <li><img src="images/8.png" alt="Art Supplies"></li>
        <li><img src="images/9.png" alt="Colouring In"></li>
        <li><img src="images/10.png" alt="Gifts"></li>
        <li><img src="images/11.png" alt="Office Furniture"></li>
        <li><img src="images/12.png" alt="Bibles"></li>
        <li><img src="images/13.png" alt="Bible Repairs &amp; Indexing"></li>
        <li><img src="images/14.png" alt="Bible Verse"></li>
    </ul>
```

With only one of the two scripts in my head (either the slicknav or the bxslider) it works perfectly. If I have both though only the lowest one in the head code works.

I have tried moving them around to change the order, placing the scripts in my html below the elements instead of using $(document).ready() and placing both into one $(document).ready() section.

Any advice on how to get these two to work together would be greatly appreciated, or even just an explanation as to what the issue is to try and avoid it in the future.

Comment: Are there any console errors? Also I don't think you need to name your functions, i.e. remove ` function menu()` and `function slideshow ()` as you want to call your libraries instead of placing the logic which calls the library into a new function.

Comment: `../../js/jquery.slicknav.min.js` and `./js/jquery.bxslider.min.js` seem to be in different directories. It isn't essentially a problem but just cross-check if the paths are correct.

Comment: `<script src="../../js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="./js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>` are using two different directories. Sounds like your scripts are stored in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

I replaced all the references to your Scripts with scripts stored on CDN's (Content Delivery Networks) this ensures that the scripts are definitely being referenced correctly.

I also swapped some of your code around to make more sense i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function menu() {
  $('#nav_menu').slicknav({
    prependTo: "#mobile_menu"
  });
});
```

**became**:

```
$(document).ready(function menu() {
  $('#mobile_menu').slicknav({
    prependTo: "#nav_menu"
  });
});
```

I added the `hidden` attribute to your `<nav id="mobile_menu" hidden="hidden">` tag so that it hides on default.

Finally I just added some links to images on Google images to test your slider.

and it seems to work as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function menu() {
  $('#mobile_menu').slicknav({
    prependTo: "#nav_menu"
  });
});

$(document).ready(function slideshow() {
  $('#slider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 10,
    slideWidth: 650,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SlickNav/1.0.10/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SlickNav/1.0.10/slicknav.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav id="nav_menu"></nav>
<nav id="mobile_menu" hidden="hidden">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="current" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="./navigation/aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="./navigation/products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Promotions</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="./navigation/backtoschool.html">Back-To-School</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> What's New</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="./navigation/latestnews.html">Latest News</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="./navigation/team.html">Our Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="./navigation/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

  <ul id="slider">
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Parrot Products"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Office Machines"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Labelling"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Paper"></li>
    <li><img src="images/5.png" alt="Files &amp; filing"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Office Accessories"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Toners &amp; Cartridges"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Art Supplies"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Colouring In"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Gifts"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Office Furniture"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Bibles"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Bible Repairs &amp; Indexing"></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Bible Verse"></li>
  </ul>
```